# How to update the payload using store selection click event in magento 2 checkout?

Tags: onestepcheckout, magento2.4.4, extension-attributes, custom-shipping-method

I have store selection option in the checkout. Customer can choose the store to pickup. When customer choosing after, i want to update the store id to payload.

I have **one step checkout**. When the shipping method click payload is updating with the default store id, When customer select the store Payload was not updating.

[image]

Currently i am updating the payload for shipping method selection like below.

requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/payload-extender': {
            'Ayakil_CustomShippingMethod/js/model/shipping-save-processor/payload-extender-mixin': true
        }
    }
}
};
```

payload-extender-mixin.js

```
define([
'jquery',
'mage/utils/wrapper',
'underscore',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address',
'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
'uiRegistry',
'Ayakil_CustomShippingMethod/js/view/shipping-option-select',
], function (
$,
wrapper,
_,
quote,
createShippingAddress,
selectShippingAddress,
checkoutData,
registry,
storeData,
) {'use strict';

return function (payloadExtender) {
    return wrapper.wrap(payloadExtender, function (originalFunction, payload) {
        payload = originalFunction(payload);
        //return payload;
        //var shippingDateValue = $('[name="pickup_store_name"]') ? $('[name="pickup_store_name"]').val() : '';
        var method = quote.shippingMethod();

        var pickupStore = '';
        var newShippingAddress,
            addressData;

        if(method['carrier_code'] === 'storepickup' && $('[name="pickup_store_name"]').val() ){
            pickupStore = $('[name="pickup_store_name"]').val();
        }
        console.log("A"+pickupStore);
        _.extend(payload.addressInformation, {
            extension_attributes: {
                'pickup_store_name': pickupStore
            }
        });
        console.log("B"+pickupStore);
        return payload;
    });
};
});
```

I have a shipping-option-select.js file to handle the click event and update the store details.

```
hasChanged: function () {
        var notEqual = this.value() !== this.initialValue;

        let store_id = this.value._latestValue;
        let currentcomponent = self;


        $.ajax({
            url:storepickupurl,
            type: 'POST',
            async:false,
            data: { 'id' : store_id },
            success:function (data) {
                currentcomponent.changeStoreInfoObj(data);
                let checkoutData = customerData.get('checkout-data')();
                //alert(data);
                $('.shipping-store-block').css('display','block');

                currentcomponent.storeAddress({
                    name: data.store_name,
                    store_email: data.store_email,
                    store_address: data.store_address1,
                    store_city: data.store_city,
                    store_zipcode: data.store_zipcode,
                    store_state: data.store_state,
                    store_country: data.store_country,
                    store_telephone: data.store_telephone
                });
                currentcomponent.isVisibleStoreInformation(true);
                //Udate checkout fields
                //$('[name="firstname"]').val(data.store_name);
                alert(data.store_name + data.store_telephone);

                //customerData.set('checkout-data', checkoutData);
                self.saveShippingInformation();
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log("There has been an error retrieving the values from the database.");
            }
        });
        console.log(self.storeAddress().name);

        return !this.visible() ? false : notEqual;
    },
```

How can i update the payload with the new store customer has choose. Please help me on this task.